# What does Nichar mean as a way killing animals?

Tags: translation, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Yoreh Deah 16:9

אין איסור" אותו ואת בנו" אלא בשחיטה בלבד, שנאמר "לא תשחטו". אבל אם ניחר (פי' ענין הנחירה הוא שתוחב הסכין בנחיריו וחותך) את הראשון, או נתנבל בידו – מותר לשחוט השני. לפיכך, חרש שוטה וקטן ששחטו את הראשון בינם לבין עצמם – מותר לשחוט השני אחריהם, לפי שרוב מעשיהם מקולקלים.

I've seen this translated as "decapitate," but literally it looks like "he stabs the knife up its nostrils and cuts" -- which is absurd, isn't it?

I found no explanation in the usual commentaries SK, BH etc. and a shochet I asked doesn't know yet.

What is nichar?!